# Close already opened workbook in Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I have created an Outlook macro that copies Outlook mails to an Excel sheet.

When the target workbook is already opened, the macro doesn't give expected results. I would like to close the already opened workbook.

I know how to do that using Excel VBA but how to deal with this using Outlook VBA.

I am using following code to check whether an Excel sheet is open.

Kindly note that I want to close the open workbook using Outlook VBA.

```
Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

On Error Resume Next
ff = FreeFile()
Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
Close ff
ErrNo = Err
On Error GoTo 0

Select Case ErrNo
Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
Case Else: Error ErrNo
End Select
End Function
```

**Updates - 1 (Code I am using to open & populate the workbook)**

```
    Dim xlWB As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object
    Dim xlApp As Object

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWB = xlApp.workbooks.Open(xlPath)
    Set xlSheet = xlWB.sheets("output")

    NextRow = xlSheet.Range("A" & xlApp.Rows.Count).End(3).Row + 1

    With xlSheet
        .cells(NextRow, "A") = Item.Subject
        .cells(NextRow, "B") = Item.ReceivedTime
        .cells(NextRow, "C") = xAsset
        .cells(NextRow, "D") = Item.SenderName
        .cells(NextRow, "E") = Item.SenderEmailAddress
    End With

    xlWB.Save
    xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
```

**Updates - 2 (Solution)**

```
Dim wb As Object
Set wb = GetObject("C:\book1.xlsx")
If Not wb is Nothing then wb.close
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show the code which populates the workbook.

Comment: @TimWilliams - I have added the code that I am using to populate the workbook. I hope this will help you to get the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just so you know, you can use GetObject to retrieve the actual document itself without the need to open an application and add a workbook. If the workbook is already open it will give you a reference to the already open instance, otherwise it will open it for you. This should allow you to avoid the issue ;)

Like:

```
Dim wb As Object
Set wb = GetObject("C:\book1.xlsx")
If not wb is nothing then debug.print wb.Name
```

You can access an existing instance of Excel using something like the below. You need to either add a reference to Microsoft Excel object library (Tools > References) or change the type of `Dim xlapp` and `Dim wb` to `As Object`. I personally prefer to add the reference to keep intellisense and early binding / compiler checks.

```
'Gets an existing instance of Excel if running then closes workbooks open in the instance,
'otherwise exits
Sub blah()
    Dim xlapp As Excel.Application

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlapp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If xlapp Is Nothing Then
        'No instance was running. You can create one with
        'Set xlapp = New Excel.Application
        'but in your case it doesn't sound like you need to so:
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In xlapp.Workbooks
        wb.Close False
    Next wb

    xlapp.Quit

End Sub
```

The process for getting a specific Application instance when multiple are running is very different so say if you need that requirement.

Comment: Worth noting that if the user happens to have more than one instance of Excel open, this will return only one instance (which may not be the one where the workbook is open).

Comment: "The process for getting a specific Application instance when multiple are running is very different so say if you need that requirement." :)

Comment: @Cor_Blimey - Thanks, I used GetObject method to get my problem solved :)