# how to close an excel workbook from ms project? (VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-project

I'm trying to create a little macro on MS project.
it would simply close a workbook already open in excel.
ideally, I would like to close one specific excel workbook, but I'd be satisfied even just being able to close excel from MS project.

it's pretty easy to find how to close a workbook I created/opened in my MS project macro, but I can't find a way to close an open workbook which was not created within my macro.

Help will be much appreciated.

I've tried to activate the workbook from MS project by opening it again, but vba says it can't open it because it's already open.

I've also tried to use
Application.SendKeys ("%{TAB}")
but ms project vba returns an error 438 "object doesn't support this method"

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303173/how-can-i-kill-task-manager-processes-through-vba-code

Comment: Don't do that--that is for killing a process that is not responding.

Comment: See: [stackoverflow.com/questions/23583695/close-already-opened-workbook-in-outlook-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583695/close-already-opened-workbook-in-outlook-vba?rq=1). This method will work just the same run from Project.

Comment: @CHill60 that works using `oProc.Terminate` without brackets. many thanks. 

Comment: @Rachel Hettinger  I've managed to rework a bit the code you proposed to make it work, thanks for that. I'm really glad to finally have a message for you, because I've used so many of your answers about MS project before. so another for the MANY other things you've unknowingly helped me with those last years. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, using the proposal of @Rachel Hettinger, I managed to finalize a function to close one specific excel workbook from MS project.

important :
this works for MS project, but I'm not sure it would for any other office applications.
(definitely not on excel, on which it would be way simpler)

```
Function CloseWorkbook(WorkbookToClose As String)

    'the name of the file you want to close (the variable WorkbookToClose above)
    'must contain the name of the file and the extension
    Dim xlapp As Object
    On Error GoTo Error_handler

    Set xlapp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    Dim wb As Object
    For Each wb In xlapp.Workbooks
        If wb.Name = WorkbookToClose Then
            wb.Close False
        End If
    Next wb

Error_handler:

End Function
```

Comment: note : I could not find out why yet, but in some cases (rare) when several workbooks are open, the macro doesn't close the required workbook, and an error message is displayed. I'll update the macro if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

after a few days of tests, I recommend to use the kill function proposed by @Chill60 instead.
link [kill excel application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303173/how-can-i-kill-task-manager-processes-through-vba-code)

the macro to close one workbook doesn't close it most of the time unfortunately.
the macro to kill excel works all the time.